# Macro in Access to prompt for file path when importing file

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I am trying to import an Excel spreadsheet into Access 2013 using a macro. Is there a way to make the macro prompt for a file path instead of having a static file path? I would like to have a message box or something similar be provided to the user to define the file path for each Excel file they would like to import. Is there a macro for this?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a InputBox via vba

```
Dim p As String
p = InputBox("please input file path")
Debug.Print p
```

I am not sure however how to achieve the same thing with just a macro.

Answer (score 0):

Use this function:

```
Function seleccionarArchivo()
     Set f = Application.FileDialog(3)
     f.AllowMultiSelect = False
     f.Filters.Clear
     f.Filters.Add "Todos", "*.*"

     If f.Show Then
         seleccionarArchivo = f.SelectedItems.Item(1)
     End If
     Set f = Nothing
End Function
```

To try, put a button and add this in the click event:

```
      MsgBox (seleccionarArchivo)
```