# Launching a pdf file located in the current project path

Tags: ms-access, vba

I want users to be able to put the Project folder on any location of their choice. If I use:

```
Application.FollowHyperlink ("C:\Program Files(x86)\Project\reference.pdf")
```

The pdf document launches only if the user put the Project folder in the Program Files(x86) folder. Is there a way for access to refer to the current path instead? I have tried the below code with no luck.

```
Private Sub referencefile_Click()
Application.FollowHyperlink (".\reference.pdf")
End Sub
```

I have tried:

```
 Application.FollowHyperlink (CurrentProject.Path & "\reference.pdf"), 
 NewWindow:=True
```

This works well with txt files but not with pdf files. Any idea?

Comment: The "current path" (`CurDir`) will be whatever path was last accessed by the host application or its VBA code. If the file can be anywhere, why not prompt for the path instead? Or does "project" refer to the database file?

Comment: @Mathieu Guindon, Project is a folder that holds the front-end.

Comment: So if the front-end isn't the Access database, then the front-end should be responsible for implementing commands and following hyperlinks...

Comment: Some users wants to put the frontend on a different drive other than C: therefore the link would then be broken.

Comment: No. What I'm saying is that when your Access database has a UI and buttons that the user can click, then Access is acting as a front-end, not just a database. If your Access-VBA code needs to know the path, and users can have it anywhere, then either you [prompt the user for it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30055164/1188513), or you implement this functionality in the [actual] front-end itself.

Comment: Is there a way to implement the functionality in the OnClick subroutine of the button? something that would launch the pdf file regardless of the location as long as the file exists in the same folder as the front end file?

Comment: But you don't KNOW where the file is located, unless I'm missing something completely obvious. Therefore, you can't. This looks like an X-Y problem: trying to find a solution for X when the problem is Y. If you bring up the `reference.pdf` from the "front end", then you can easily know where the file is located and don't need to prompt or assume anything. Is the "front end" an Excel worksheet? Some VBA project? A .NET application?

Comment: Assuming Access db is executing code, `CurrentProject.Path` will return folder path of the Access db. So if PDF file is in same folder as the Access db, `CurrentProject.Path & "\reference.pdf'`. If the PDF is not in that location then referencing `CurrentProject.Path` is not useful.

Comment: Yes all in the same folder.

Comment: I have tried     Application.FollowHyperlink (CurrentProject.Path & "\reference.pdf"), NewWindow:=True    with no luck. The code however works well for txt files. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

After a Quick Check and ensuring that my pdf file was not corrupted.

```
Application.FollowHyperlink (CurrentProject.Path & "\reference.pdf"), NewWindow:=True
```

The above code works fine as long as the pdf file exits in the same location as the front end. If you have ever thought of eliminating the security warning that access gives when you manually enter a hyperlink to a control button's properties, this code may be a good solution.